# Help analysing a 4-way mixed ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, mixed-model

I am analysing a study using a 4-way mixed ANOVA. It has one between-subjects factor and 3 within-subjects factors (with 2, 2, and 3 levels).

I have 9 dependent variables. I ran normality tests on my data, and since it is a 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 ANOVA, I had to run 24 tests per dependent variable. At least one of the tests with each variable is not normal (the Shapiro-Wilkes test is significant). Transforming the data makes the data even less 'normal'.

Since there are no non-parametric tests for mixed ANOVAs, what can I do?

I noticed in other similar questions sometimes people talk about the residuals being normal, but how do I check this?

Thanks for any help you can give me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: What's your sample size? Tests of normality are useless if your sample size is moderate (or larger) because, in the real world, all data are non-normal.

Comment: Thanks for replying! My sample size is 63 - 29 in one group and 34 in the other.

Comment: Just to add, I looked at the Normal Q-Q plots for the residuals and they don't appear to follow the normal curve perfectly, but they don't deviate away from it too much either. One of my variables has a clear positive skew pattern, because many participants gave zero as their answer to it. Therefore, transformations wouldn't work, right? It seems like my only option would be to run the mixed ANOVA, but would it be valid?

Comment: I also ran the ANOVA using a square root transformed version of the data, and now some of the variables are significant that weren't before. It's left me more confused about what to do!